# RTL8822BE unable to connect to WiFi networks Ubuntu 18.04 Kernel 5.3

Tags: networking, 18.04, drivers, realtek-wireless

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I've been struggling with a wifi-related issue for the past few months - ever since Ubuntu has started to use the 5.x kernel.

As of now, I'm running 5.3.0-51-generic that was automatically installed using apt-update/upgrade.

The problem is - I can find all wifi networks around me but cannot connect to any of them.
I tried running the following commands but with no success:

```
git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git -b rtw88
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

The thing is, sometimes when I mess around for a few hours it somehow starts working properly, but the next day it doesn't and I have no idea what is causing this issue / what is fixing it.

I'm using ASUS FX570UD Laptop, with Realtek RTL8822BE wireless card.

I'm attaching the outputs of dmesg, lspci -vvvnn, lshw -C network and lsmod -- all after installing the repo.

I'm a pretty beginner linux user, and will gladly provide any additional necessary logs.

Thanks in advance and sorry for any English mistakes!

For your convenience, I've pasted the attached logs on pastebin so you won't have to download them :-)

dmesg - https://pastebin.com/Pxv8GbZ7

lspci -vvvnn - https://pastebin.com/0NxaYyQb

lshw - https://pastebin.com/U9SxYMcb

lsmod - https://pastebin.com/ub8uXffC